Pyspark <3.3 Extract all regex and replace with another DataFrame
Using pyspark 3.3 (no regexp_extract_all), I'd like to take a column of values
+-------------------------+
|          value          |
+-------------------------+
|  MONOCYTES 1511|A5905.5 |
+-------------------------+


the data format is not constant. ie. The value could also be 1511;MONO->A5905.5

And extract all parts that match the regex r'\w?\d+\.?\d*'. Then, I'd like to replace any extracted value with the value from another dataframe:
+-----------+--------------+
|    code   |     value    |
+-----------+--------------+
|    1511   |  monocytes1  |
+-----------+--------------+
|  A5905.5  |  monocytes2  |
+-----------+--------------+

Such that I can somehow map {"MONOCYTES 1511|A5905.5": ["monocytes1", "monocytes2"]}
What is the fastest way to do this given the version constraint?

Is the number of codes in values constant?

You can use a UDF:
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
import re


def _find(s):
    return re.findall(r'\w?\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)

def _replace(parts):
    return [D.get(part, part) for part in parts]


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ReplaceValues").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([("MONOCYTES 1511|A5905.5",)], ["value"])

TP = [("1511", "monocytes1"), ("A5905.5", "monocytes2")]
CDF = spark.createDataFrame(TP, ["code", "value"])

D = {row['code']: row['value'] for row in CDF.collect()}

UDF = F.udf(_find, ArrayType(StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("udf vals", UDF(F.col("value")))

REP = F.udf(_replace, ArrayType(StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("final values", REP(F.col("udf vals")))
df.select("value", "final values").show(truncate=False)



Thank you!! This works, but UDFs are slower. Is there any implementation that doesn't require a UDF?

Try and see if you could use expr. Can't think of anything now....
